# Add and call Function to and from Dict in Julia

Tags: julia

assume I have a Dict

```
acts = Dict{String, Function}()
```

and I have a function foo()

```
function foo(arg1, arg2)
  @info arg1
  @info arg2
end
```

First, How can I store "bar" => foo() in acts Dict?

Second, How can I call bar from acts and run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be straightforward:

```
julia> acts = Dict{String, Function}()
Dict{String,Function} with 0 entries

julia> function foo(arg1, arg2)
           @info arg1
           @info arg2
       end 
foo (generic function with 1 method)

# add function foo to dict acts with key "bar"
julia> acts["bar"] = foo
foo (generic function with 1 method)

# check that it's there
julia> acts
Dict{String,Function} with 1 entry:
  "bar" => foo

# call the foo function from the dict by using its key
julia> acts["bar"]("hi", 2)
[ Info: hi
[ Info: 2
```